# Wavefunction for multi-particle systems

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, identical-particles

[image]

As described in the photo(the explanation is given below Equation 11.1.2) we always have one wave function for many-particle systems as well. Then the author describes how an attempt to have the composite wave
function as the product of individual wave functions would fail since the Hamiltonian couples the degree of freedom of the particles via a potential. However, What if we consider two free particles (to avoid the problems arising from identicalness, we assume one to be a boson and another to be a fermion), and then write the wave function of the composite system , wouldn't that wave function be the product of the bosonic wave function and the fermionic wave function?
The photo has been taken from Professor Barton Zwiebach's book:-"Mastering Quantum Mechanics, essentials theory and applications "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Zwiebach talks about is the general case. What you describe is a very special case of the two-particle wavefunction of two distinguishable particles. In this latter case, the total function $\psi(r_1, r_2)$ indeed factorizes into a product of individual single-particle wavefunctions $\psi(r_1)$ and $\phi(r_2)$. As you undoubtedly know very well, already at the immediate next level of complication, - two indistinguishable particles, -  the two-particle wavefuntion $\psi(r_1, r_2) = \psi(r_1) \phi(r_2) \pm \psi(r_1) \phi(r_2)$, which is obviously not a simple product $\psi(r_1)$ and $\phi(r_2)$.

In the more general case (relativistic high-energy physics, or many-body condensed matter system), even the number of particles is not fixed, and $\psi(r_1, r_2)$ can only be decomposed into infinite sum of arbitrary products of single-particle states.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @John could you write down one explicit wavefunction (just the basic exponential terms at t=0) of an "indistinguishable" particle, please?

Comment: @James I am not sure if I understood your question correctly, but do you mean this expression: $\psi(r_1, r_2) = \psi(r_1) \phi(r_2) \pm \psi(r_1) \phi(r_2)$? Here, "+" is for two indistinguishable bosons, and "-" is for fermions.

Answer (score 1):

> Then the author describes how an attempt to have the composite wave function as the product of individual wave functions would fail since ***the Hamiltonian couples the degree of freedom of the particles via a potential.***

(emphasis is mine)

There are two reasons why one cannot use product wave functions:

- The particle indistinguishability - which requires using symmetrized or anti-symmetrized wave function. This is not a constraint, if one particle is a fermion and another is a boson. This is also not a constraint when talking about an electron and a proton, since the two are distinguishable, even if both are fermions.
- The interaction between two particles, which means that the wave function is no more separable in [the sense that one separates variables in math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables): that is, if
  $\psi_p(\mathbf{x}_p)$ and $\psi_e(\mathbf{x}_e)$ are eigenfunctions of Hamilronians
  $H_p=\frac{\mathbf{p}_p^2}{2m_p}$ and $H_e=\frac{\mathbf{p}_e^2}{2m_e}$, then their product will be eigenfunction of Hamiltonian $H_p=\frac{\mathbf{p}_p^2}{2m_p}+\frac{\mathbf{p}_e^2}{2m_e}$ but not of $H_p=\frac{\mathbf{p}_p^2}{2m_p}+\frac{\mathbf{p}_e^2}{2m_e} + V(|\mathbf{x}_p-\mathbf{x}_e|)$. Of course, the eigenfunctions of the latter could be expanded in terms of the eigenfunctions of the non-interacting Hamiltonian,  but in cases like Hydrogen atom this is counterproductive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.